# How to create polygon shape from coordinates returned by GeoJSON

Tags: javascript, geojson, babylonjs

I have GeoJSON, with stored building data as coordinates.

If I drag and drop it on google maps, shape will be rendered. I want to learn how to create polygonal shape in `babylon.js` from data coded in GeoJSON. JSON I'm talking about:

```
{
   "type":"FeatureCollection",
   "features":[
      {
         "id":"w26358613",
         "properties":{
            "levels":8
         },
         "geometry":{
            "type":"Polygon",
            "coordinates":[
               [
                  [ 13.426791, 52.518344 ],
                  [ 13.426866, 52.518303 ],
                  [ 13.426951, 52.51826  ],
                  [ 13.427045, 52.518216 ],
                  [ 13.427139, 52.518175 ],
                  [ 13.427233, 52.518136 ],
                  [ 13.427341, 52.518095 ],
                  [ 13.427484, 52.518046 ],
                  [ 13.427489, 52.51805  ],
                  [ 13.42749,  52.51805  ],
                  [ 13.427493, 52.518052 ],
                  [ 13.427677, 52.518013 ],
                  [ 13.427653, 52.517971 ],
                  [ 13.427668, 52.517968 ],
                  [ 13.42762,  52.517885 ],
                  [ 13.427605, 52.517887 ],
                  [ 13.42758,  52.517846 ],
                  [ 13.427396, 52.517885 ],
                  [ 13.427435, 52.517952 ],
                  [ 13.427253, 52.518014 ],
                  [ 13.427237, 52.517997 ],
                  [ 13.427073, 52.51806  ],
                  [ 13.427092, 52.518077 ],
                  [ 13.426946, 52.51814  ],
                  [ 13.426927, 52.518124 ],
                  [ 13.426775, 52.518198 ],
                  [ 13.426796, 52.518213 ],
                  [ 13.426662, 52.518285 ],
                  [ 13.426639, 52.518271 ],
                  [ 13.426558, 52.518318 ],
                  [ 13.426502, 52.518353 ],
                  [ 13.426503, 52.518354 ],
                  [ 13.426483, 52.518366 ],
                  [ 13.426559, 52.518474 ],
                  [ 13.426651, 52.51845  ],
                  [ 13.426643, 52.518438 ],
                  [ 13.426647, 52.518436 ],
                  [ 13.426641, 52.518433 ],
                  [ 13.426727, 52.51838  ],
                  [ 13.426791, 52.518344 ]
               ]
            ]
         },
         "type":"Feature"
      }
   ]
}
```

Google maps rendered this form this JSON:
[image: 1]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've got in GeoJSON are geographic coordinates of your polygon's points. What Google Maps API do is choosing a projection from those coordinates to a 2D coordinate system, which can be drawn on a map. IIRC, Google Maps API uses [spherical Mercator projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection). So, if you use formulas from the projection you choose (strongly suggest Mercator for that) you'll get set of 2D coordinated you could use to create polygon in Babylon.js use, e.g. [`PolygonMeshBuilder`](http://doc.babylonjs.com/classes/2.4/PolygonMeshBuilder).